# regex reject if found

Tags: java, regex

I've already received some help here, but I'm having a slightly different problem. I'm looking to find cases where a `DocumentBuilderFactory` is created, but hasn't restricted the `ExpandEntityReferences`. I have the following regex:

```
(?x)

# finds DocumentBuilderFactory creation and pulls out the variable name
# of the form DocumentBuilderFactory VARNAME = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance
# then checks if that variable name has one of three acceptable ways to stop XXE attacks
# matches any instance where the variable is initialized, but not restricted

(?:
   # This is for DocumentBuilderFactory VARNAME = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance with many possible alternates
   DocumentBuilderFactory
   [\s]+?
   (\w+)
   [\s]*?
   =
   [\s]*?
   (?:.*?DocumentBuilderFactory)
   [.\s]+
   newInstance.*

   # checks that the var name is NOT (using ?!) using one of the acceptable rejection methods
   (?!\1[.\s]+
      (?:setFeature\s*\(\s*"http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities"\s*,\s*false\s*\)
        |setFeature\s*\(\s*"http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl"\s*,\s*false\s*\)
        |setExpandEntityReferences\s*\(\s*false\s*\))
   )
)
```

and a test file could look like this:

```
// Set the parser properties
  javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
  factory.setValidating(false);
  factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
  factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
  factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
  factory.setCoalescing(true);
  javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
```

Is there any way to have this regex run on this file and the regex fails (because it correctly sets `factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);` ?

Updated:

```
(?:
   DocumentBuilderFactory
   \s+
   (\w+)
   \s*
   =
   \s*
   (?:.*?DocumentBuilderFactory)
   \s*.\s*
   newInstance.*
   (?:[\s\S](?!
      \1\s*.\s*
      (?:setFeature\s*\(\s*"http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities"\s*,\s*false\s*\)
      |setFeature\s*\(\s*"http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl"\s*,\s*false\s*\)
      |setExpandEntityReferences\s*\(\s*false\s*\))
   ))*$
)
```

And it doesn't find() successfully, as expected; however, if I misspell factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false) as factory.setExpandEntity##References(false) I would expect the regex to be found, but it is not. Is there a way to get this feature to work?

Comment: Shouldn't you use double backslash instead of one in `\r\n\s\w` since this is Java ? Note that you don't need to escape a dot in a character class, so `[.]` is valid and will match a dot :)

Comment: To add to @HamZa, you can just write `\s` instead of `[\s\r\n]`.

Comment: @HamZa yes you are correct, I removed to make it pure regex, but yes in my file it is double slashed.

Comment: @acheong87 awesome! I've changed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Test for a string *not* existing to the end:

```
(?:.(?!xyz))*$
```

It basically means, "Every single character from this point forth, must *not* be followed by `xyz`." Since `.` doesn't match newlines though, you might want to generalize it to:

```
(?:[\s\S](?!xyz))*$
   ^^^^^^
```

(It's union of complementary sets, therefore *truly* all characters.)

To apply this to your case, just replace `xyz` with the thing you don't want appearing anywhere:

```
   # checks that the var name is NOT (using ?!) using one of the acceptable rejection methods
   (?:[\s\S](?!
       \1[.\s]+
       (?:setFeature\s*\(\s*"http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities"\s*,\s*false\s*\)
         |setFeature\s*\(\s*"http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl"\s*,\s*false\s*\)
         |setExpandEntityReferences\s*\(\s*false\s*\))
   ))*$
```

### Use word boundaries to match whole words (like identifiers):

Surely, when working with, say, `factory`, you wouldn't want to match `old_factory`! Use word boundaries to ensure you're capturing entire words.

In your case, just add a `\b` before the `\1`:

```
\b\1
```

### Simplify your character classes and escape literal dots:

As mentioned in the comments, `\s` includes `\r` and `\n`, so you can rewrite `[\s\r\n]` as `\s` (without the brackets).

Also, you'd want to change instances like

```
newInstance.*
```

to

```
newInstance[.]*
```

Wildcards do *not* behave like `\s` or `\w` within a character class: `.` just means a literal dot within a character class.

Comment: I've added your info, and updated my question. it sort of works, but I may have misunderstood what you explained. Can you take a look?

Comment: Could you try replacing the `$` with `(?![\s\S])`?

Comment: Your exact regex is working for me. Make sure you're escaping your backslashes though, and also try escaping your forward slashes. Here is an online example with the word misspelled (###) and thus the segment matching: http://www.myregextester.com/?r=e20a74bc. And here is the same example but with the word spelled correctly, and thus the match failing: http://www.myregextester.com/?r=b259f8ac.

Comment: well I'm confused. it works in pure java, but not in the java usecase I have. I guess this may point to a regex engine difference. Either way, you are correct. I'll work out why my results don't show the same for in each java case. Thank you

Comment: forget it. I forgot to put in(?x) first. you're correct. It's great. Thanks for your help